# Can we have an option to hide the tags that are synonyms on the tag page

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, tags-page

I was looking at a question today that only had 1 tag. The [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag.
I read the question and was wondering which tags I could add to this question, to make it more noticeable.

So I took off to the [Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) page and sorted alphabetical to have a quick glance over a few starting letters to see what tags I could use for that question. That is when I noticed the tags page is extremely bloated with (mostly) useless tags, as all tags that are synonyms of other tags are listed as well. Then I wondered how many of these synonyms are there?

Currently the tag's page has a pagination that runs up to and including 46. Each containing 2<sup>5</sup> questions per page, except for page 46 that currently has only 2 tags, which makes a total of 1442 "tags".

If we sort by popularity we find that halfway page 36 the tags with 0 questions start to be listed. From this we can calculate that in total there are (1442 - 1136 =) 306 tags that are synonyms.

If we consider these synonyms as noise, and the true tags as signal, we have a signal to noise ratio of 1136:306 or 3.71:1.

Can we please make this ∞ : 1 by having an option to hide the synonyms, or alternatively hide them by default and have an option to display them?

Comment: as a fun exercise I decided to write this jquery line which you can run in your browser's developer console to hide (and reveal if run again) tags with 0 questions on the current page: `$('#tags-browser .s-card.js-tag-cell .grid--cell').each(function(){ console.log($(this).text()); if ($(this).text() == "0 questions") $(this).parent().parent().toggle(); });` but overall I think you should try to use Data.SE instead of the normal public tags page if you intend to spend a significant amount of time with tags